# why nested array object not work in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is a grid component what receive a prop as searchElement to rendering search segment of the grid.some dropdowns options is empty and should fill by async request after component mounted.
after I call async fetch in componentDidMount and assign new options to searchElements something is wrong because in grid component console.log show searchElements[0] have a property as options which contains array with many elements but when I do console.log searchElements[0].options it's empty !!!!!

```
let SearchTerms = [
    {
        key    : "supervisor",
        label  : "Supervisor",
        type   : GRID_DROPDOWN_TYPE,
        options: [],
        col    : 2
    },
.
.
.
    class CommentComponent ..... {
    ...

async componentWillMount() {
    let GetSupervisors = await fetchWith(`${entry_point}/users`, "GET", {roles: 5}, dispatch, true);
    if (GetSupervisors.ok && GetSupervisors.result['hydra:totalItems'] > 0) {
                    Supervisors = GetSupervisors.result['hydra:member'];
    }

    SearchTerms[0].options = Supervisors.map(data => ({
         value: data.id,
         label: data.fullname
    }));
}
```

then I'll pass SearchTerms to GridComponent

```
<GridComponent searchElements={SearchTerms} ...
```

Now in GridComponent :

```
getSearchElements = () => {
        const {searchElements, preloader, process, searchMode} = this.props;
        console.log(searchElements[0]);
        let SearchElements = [];
```

Problem is here : 
When I come to CommentComponent through Route Click everything is ok but When I refresh the page SearchElement[0].options is empty :(

Comment: also use `componentDidMount` instead of deprecated `componentWillMount`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SearchTerms as the state

```
class CommentComponent ..... {
 state = {
    SearchTerms: [
    {
        key    : "supervisor",
        label  : "Supervisor",
        type   : GRID_DROPDOWN_TYPE,
        options: [],
        col    : 2
    },
}
.
.
.

  async componentWillMount() {
    let GetSupervisors = await fetchWith(`${entry_point}/users`, "GET", {roles: 
 5}, dispatch, true);
    if (GetSupervisors.ok && GetSupervisors.result['hydra:totalItems'] > 0) {
                    Supervisors = GetSupervisors.result['hydra:member'];
    }

   const newSearchTerms = [...this.state.SearchTerms]
    newSearchTerms[0].options = Supervisors.map(data => ({
         value: data.id,
         label: data.fullname
    }));
    this.setState({SearchTerms:newSearchTerms })
}
```

Comment: you are using `componentWillMount` which is deprecated.

Comment: @JuniusL. Good advice, compoentWillMount will be deprecated, it is recommended to use componentDidMount

Comment: It's worked. you gotta be kidding meeee, I'v tried every solution also as a state but didn't work since yesterday . now it's work . :) .